# How can I set WheelColliders to free-roll when on an incline?

Tags: unity-game-engine, wheelcollider

I imported the Vehicles package and dropped a car into my scene. I placed it on a plan with a rotation of 10 degrees. I would like the car to free-roll when on an incline. Can anyone tell me how to achieve that please?

Comment: Realistically, every single Unity project that has cars in it just uses Edy's Vehicle Physics. You can spend two man-years developing a car rig, or drop in Edy's.  There's no realistic alternative.

Comment: @JoeBlow Do you know how to configure a prefab from that library to allow free-rolling?

Comment: Hi.  Merely becoming expert with E.V.S. is a major job.  (Allow some weeks.)  Once you are expert with it, you will have no problem whatsoever doing what you are doing.  I think you are ***drastically*** underestimating how complicated it is to make "a game with vehicles".  A game with vehicles will typically have 4+ full-time senior engineers working on the vehicle physics.

Comment: I was not asking to be an instant expert, I was asking if the feature is supported. It turns out the standard wheel colliders do in fact free-roll, but not if you just start the vehicle off on a slope. You have to drop the vehicle slightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had to place the initial position of the vehicle just slightly above ground level when my game starts. That way it falls slightly, and the movement then seems to trigger Unity3D to start checking for movement.